# Why use ROI if I can use effective compount interest?

Tags: investing, compound-interest

According to Wikipedia,

> [return on investment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_investment) = (gain from investment – cost of investment) /
>   cost of investment

However this calculation does not take into account the time passed between the invest and the return, so if I want to be able to compare different products, shouldn't I *always* calculate the effective compound interest rate?

```
i = (FV/PV)^(1/n) - 1
```

Comment: Do you always know the future value and time span to plug into the formula?

Comment: @JBKing, yes, assuming I'm looking at past data (which is always the case I guess)

Comment: In view of the formula that you attribute to Wikipedia, if I invested $1000 into something (`cost of investment`) and received $1100 when I sold the investment, is my `gain on investment` $1100 or $100? That formula looks awfully weird unless `gain on investment` is supposed to mean the proceeds of the sale of the investment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes though I'd likely put a caveat on that. If you take short-term investments and extrapolate the results to get an annual result this can be misleading. For example, if a stock goes up 10% in a month, assuming this will continue for the next 11 months may not be a great idea. Thus, beware of how much data do you have in making these calculations.

---

When looking at long-term investments, the compound annual growth rate can be quite useful for comparison.

Comment: so in long term investments one shouldn't look in ROI, right?